# Using the wrong module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pygame

I'm programming a game with pygame, but when I try to use the python's `math` module, my program tries to use `pygame.math` instead. How can I solve this issue?

**Example:**

```
import pygame, math
from pygame import *
pygame.init()
a = math.sin(90)
# some code that uses a
```

**Error message:**

```
AttributeError: module 'pygame.math' has no attribute 'sin'
```

The error might be because of from pygame import *, but my code doesn't work without it.
**Solved in the commments:**

Comment: Did you place your code inside the `pygame` folder for some reason?

Comment: Did you do `from pygame import *`? There aren't many ways that this could happen, and most of them involve you doing something relevant that you're not telling us.

Comment: On my computer the given code throws no errors. Show us the code that you are actually using.

Comment: @user2357112 True, I forgot to add that to the example.

Comment: *Don't use `import *`.* This kind of thing is why. If you need `pygame`'s contents, use them explicitly as `pygame.whatever`.

Comment: @user2357112 I have a line of code: "if event.type == QUIT: , and it needs from pygame import *", so does it work if I put it like this: "if event.type == pygame.QUIT:" ?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly! Otherwise you could do `from pygame.locals import *` which [only imports the constants](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html). Although, I personally like to use `if event.type == pygame.QUIT` for explicitness.

Comment: Thanks for help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Use the code as following, as it will prevent errors:

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.init()
a = math.sin(90)
```

This way it imports as **separate** modules. You had it saying:

1. Import Pygame and Pygame Math
2. Initiate Pygame
3. define variable "a"

Comment: The asker's code also imports the modules as separate modules; it does not import pygame.math at all. If you write `import pygame, math` in your code it'll work exactly as before.

Comment: Yes, importing modules on one line or on multiple lines will yield the same result. Your code and the original code in the question was equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I use pygame and math in my code but I have them as separate imports:

```
import pygame
import math
```

And everything works as expected without error

Comment: Importing on the same line is no different than importing on separate lines, except that PEP8 suggest the latter.

Comment: True @TedKleinBergman, I did not know you could import onto the same line. I just always imported on different lines by default.